# Enviar json con axios.post a controlador laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, post, axios

Tengo la ruta hacia el controlador:

```
Route::post('/updateCart', 'ProductInShoppingCartsController@update')
          ->middleware('auth')
          ->name('updateCart');
```

El método en javascript (toma los datos de acuerdo a los id y el json lo genera perfecto):

```
axios.post('/updateCart', {
      product_id : document.getElementById('prodid'+i).value,
      cant : quantity,
      shopping_cart_id : document.getElementById('shopid').value
    })
    .then((resp)=>{
      console.log(resp);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
```

y la función en el controlador laravel:

```
  public function update($data)
  {
     $datos = json_decode($data);
     … actualizo en mi bd
     return "Actualizado con éxito";
  }
```

He tratado de simplificar lo más posible esta consulta porque recibo el error 500 al ejecutar el envío post, supongo que algo estoy definiendo mal pero no encuentro qué:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 500
at e.exports (app.min.js:1)
at e.exports (app.min.js:1)
at XMLHttpRequest.p.onreadystatechange (app.min.js:1)
```

Comment: Revisa los logs de laravel en `storage/logs/laravel.log` para ver de que se trata el error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error 500 indica que tu servidor recibió tu solicitud pero no se pudo procesar, el error esta en tu controlador porque estas accediendo a la variable $data que no hace referencia a nada pues se esta enviando por post, para acceder a la data debes tener el request así

```
     public function update(Request $request)
      {
         $product_id= $request->product_id;
         $cant=$request->cant;
         $shopping_cart_id=$request->shopping_cart_id;
         … aca coloca to logica
         return "Actualizado con éxito";
      }
```

recuerda que debes importar la clase Request en la parte de arriba

Comment: Muchas gracias, solucionado.